# HttpClient: Not able to connect to the service from WCF service. Same working fine from a console application

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm trying to connect to a API with the below code,

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("OcpApimSubscriptionKey"));
                var response = client.GetAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GeturlPackages")).Result;



                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fetching succeeded!");
                }
                else
                {                        
                    throw new Exception("Fetching failed! Response status :( " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
                }
            }
```

The code fetches the required response from a new console application built with v4.6 .Net framework, but it is not working from the existing WCF service built with v4.6 .Net framework.

Please let me know if anyone had faced any similar issue.

**Exception details:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

Comment: Hi Aryan! Could you confirm if your "GeturlPackages" is being parsed correctly? I don't see anything weird in your code. Try wrapping the     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GeturlPackages") into a Uri e.g. new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GeturlPackages"))

Comment: I see what the issue is,

In my web.config in the WCF service, it is using <defaultProxy> settings, which is causing the issue,

<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://proxy:8080"/>
    </defaultProxy>

Can one please let me know why this could be causing an issue?